# Why collections of owned types generate an Id and how can I avoid that?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, domain-driven-design

As Microsoft says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) :

> Owned entities are essentially a part of the owner and cannot exist without it, they are conceptually similar to aggregates

It means in DDD architecture (Domain Driven Design) we can use owned types (or collection of owned types ) as an entity inside an aggregation or as a value object. On the other hand, we know that ValueObject in DDD has no Identity value because of its structure and its Immutability. I want to know if I decide to use the Owned type to implement the value object how can I force it to avoid making Id in the creation table?

For example, as you see in the following picture (that Microsoft mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)) when we use a collection of owned types, EF makes an "Id" field in the table that no sense in Address Value Object! How to avoid it? and Is it really a correct option?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example is from the `OwnsMany` scenario where it clearly explains that it needs a FK in the table to associate address***es*** back to their Distributor. How else would an Address record associate back to the Distriburor when loading the entities?

If a Distributor only has 0-1 address then you don't need an OwnerId on Address, the Address' Id column would serve as PK and FK back to the Distributor. EF needs a "Key" on each table to uniquely identify each row. You could possibly avoid an "Id" column by mapping a composite key, essentially:

```
public class Address
{
    [Key, Column(0), ForeignKey("Owner")]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(1)]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(2)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual Distributor Owner { get; set; }
}
```

A dedicated unique, and DB Generated Id column for the Address table IMO makes more sense than a large, composite key of strings and FK.

Ownership as far as the database is concerned is identical to `HasOne` / `HasMany` in the way the schema is laid out & relational rules. What differentiates `OwnsMany` from `HasMany` is how EF will allow you to access those owned entities. You cannot have a `DbSet<Address>`, only access Addresses through it's Distributor.  It serves no real purpose except to scratch particular design pattern itches. :)